# Rails and gems update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to create app with command

> grails new appp

and it creates 2 directories: new and appp. I reckon that I should update my rails or gems version. How can I do that? I use UBUNTU 10.04

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the following command:

```
gem update rails
```

Comment: it gives an error: Updating installed gems
Updating rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:1

Comment: what version of rails are you using? You can see this by running rails -v

Comment: Then you should instead try installing new version. Just do "install rails -v 3.1"

Comment: [Here](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html) you have the full guide to install rails 3.1.1